# How to determine what program is writing error log every 10 seconds?

Tags: python, automation

A long time ago on my Macbook I worked through an online tutorial on automating tasks: [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter14/).

I've since gotten a new laptop. On the new laptop, I've tried to get rid of the folder that contained the files for this tutorial (the folder was named "boring"), but the folder is always, within seconds, recreated automatically with an empty stdout.log and a stderr.log file that, every 10 seconds, has this line written to it:

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'weatherAlert.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

[image]

Unfortunately this log doesn't make clear what program generated it.

There was a `weatherAlert.py` file that was part of the boring folder, but it indeed doesn't exist anymore because I deleted it, and I don't want to have to recreate it just to stop this error logging from happening.

I've searched for "weatherAlert.py" in the Finder and found nothing aside from this error log file.

It seems the automation tutorial was a little overly effective and I somehow configured a program to try to invoke the `weatherAlert.py` file every 10 seconds forever.

I've gone into Activity Monitor and quit a process I found called `weatherd`, but that didn't stop the logs.

Restarting my computer doesn't fix anything.

How can I find this recurring program and stop it?

Comment: Shades on Fantasia.  You could reinstall python.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the Python folder at `/Library /Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7` stopped the log creation.

Comment: That looks like you removed python from your system. It's bound to cause problems in the future.   weatherAlert.py seems to be connected to AppDaemon https://community.home-assistant.io/t/appdaemon-severe-weather-alert-app/10274